# How to get and compare values in table from another table in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new at angularjs. So, it might be fool question.Anyway, please let me explain my problem. I have a table which is listed by ng-repeat and I'd like to change a column datas with another datas in another table column.

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat=" list in listTypes">
                            <td>{{list.Comments}}</td>
                            <td>{{list.Modul}}</td>
                            <td>{{list.UserId}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-repeat="user in userNames">{{user.UserName}}</td>
```

I want to get UserName instead of UserId, but the problem that UserName is recorded in another table. Here is my angular for getting listTypes :

```
 $scope.GetList = function () {
        var onSuccess = function (response, status) {
            //1
            $scope.listTypes = response.Data;



            var str = response.Data;
            $scope.listTypes = eval('(' + str + ')');
            for (var key in $scope.listTypes) {
                $scope.listTypes[key].selected = "";
            }
            $scope.GetUserNames();
        };
        var data = null;
        var request = $rest.GetList(data);
        NGTools.CallNgServiceWithRequest(request, onSuccess, "GetList");
    };
```

And trying to get usernames with this code:

```
$scope.userdatas= [];
        $scope.userNames = [];
        $scope.GetUserNames = function () {
            var onSuccess = function (response, status) {
                //1
                $scope.userNames = response.Data;

            };
            $scope.userdatas= $scope.listTypes.UserId;
            var data = { userdatas: JSON.stringify( $scope.userdatas) };
            var request = $rest.GetUserNames(data);
            NGTools.CallNgServiceWithRequest(request, onSuccess, "GetUserNames");
        };
```

but it doesn't work. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with this code block. Please let me know if any tip is available. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have to collections in your scope - one of which holds the id of the user, and the other holding the name, like so:

```
$scope.users =  [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Janice Doe' } ];

$scope.userInfo = [
    { userId: 1, gender: 'male' },
    { userId: 2, gender: 'female' },
    { userId: 3, gender: 'female' }];
```

Then what you could do is ng-repeat over the one with the userInfo and in your binding expression - use the id to get the name from the other collection:

```
        <li ng-repeat="item in userInfo">
            {{ item.gender }} {{ getNameFor(item.userId) }}</li>
```

Where the getNameFor is defined as:

```
$scope.getNameFor = function(id) {
    var user = $scope.users.filter(function(item) { return item.id === id })[0];
    console.log(user);
    return user.name;
```

Which I checked in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/01kmoxw9/

Comment: Welcome - please note that Array.prototype.filter is IE 8 and up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter